# How to parse request.getParameter() value efficiently?

Tags: java, httprequest

I am parsing the request parameters value in the following way

1.**Parsing a BOOLEAN value**

```
boolean isWebView = false;

if((request.getParameter("isVebView")) != null) {
isWebView = Boolean.valueOf(request.getParameter("isVebView")).booleanValue();
}
```

2.**Parsing an INTERGER value**

```
int scope = 0;

if(request.getParameter("scope") != null){
    scope = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("scope"));
}
```

Checking agains null each time and casting their value - I feel some burden in doing them each time. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: `boolean isWebView =  ("true".equals(request.getParameter("isVebView")));`